# Setup cPanel on CentOS, website not working

Tags: cpanel

I've setup a cPanel server on CentOS. Followed through with all the basic recommended installation options.

I've created an account - mydomain.com.au - and have been able to access the cpanel for that account through WHM.

My server's public IP is 1.2.3.4, I've created an A record in my domain register for www.mydomain.com.au -> 1.2.3.4. This does resolve correctly when checked through ping and mxtoolbox.

However, when I try to access the site www.mydomain.com.au, I get taken to "This web page is not available".

Am I missing something? I haven't setup the cPanel server with DNS hosting/private nameserver as I'm trying to get something basic going first, just a simple hosting account.

Comment: May i know you domain name to chek DNS or you can check DND error here: https://www.whoisextractor.in/dns-health-checkup/

Comment: What other error info do you get with the "This web page is not available"? Does it say that it is a DNS issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not updated the correct "A" record of your site and due to that you are getting this issues, Please update it correctly and check your domain DNS report at : http://intodns.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check that account's VirtualHost in httpd.conf, maybe it has a wrong IP.

Answer (score 0):

Point the IP address correctly to resolve the issue, if you have DNS clustering enabled and you have WHM access then you can edit it accordingly in WHM or you can contact your support that manages the nameserver's for the domain and ask them to point it.